# Composable: Adjust items size like in LazyGrid

Tags: responsive-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have my custom grid. I need to adjust size of its elements like it `weight(1f)` except for the last row when the size should be same as other (like in `LazyGrid` on the screenshot), how's it possible?

[image]

```
@Composable
fun <T> VerticalGrid(
    data: List<T>,
    columnCount: Int,
    itemContent: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    val size = data.size
    val rows = if (size == 0) 0 else 1 + (size - 1) / columnCount

    Column {
        for (rowIndex in 0..rows) {
            val itemIndex = rowIndex * columnCount
            val end = min(itemIndex + columnCount, size)

            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                for (index in itemIndex until end) {
                    itemContent(data[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not a LazyGrid  ?

Comment: It can't be used inside the other scrollable and seems overblown for fast performance of small stuff.